# How to compare nested array with regular array?

Tags: javascript

I have these two arrays, one is a nested array and one is a regular array. both containing strings.
I need to go through the regular array and assess if the elements match only the
"claims" key and "matches" key but NOT the exclusions key. What is the best way of doing this ?

```js
  const claimsArr = [
    {claim:'Protein',matches:['high in protein','^protein'],exclusions:['whey','milk']},
    {claim:'Carbs',matches:['high in carbs','^carbs'],exclusions:['sugar','lactose']},
     ]
```

```js
  DomArray = [
        "Protein", "whey" , 
      ]
```

My desired output would be an array of matched items if the DomArray contains whats in "claim" && "matches" but not "exclusion"

expected output:

```js
result = ["Protien", "whey", "high in protein" ,"protein"]
```

Comment: What does your desired output look like? Array of bools?

Comment: hi, I edited my question to state my desire output

Comment: @ShuibAbdillahi can you add the expected output for the current input as array iteslf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const claimsArr = [
  {
    claim: "Protein",
    matches: ["high in protein", "^protein"],
    exclusions: ["whey", "milk"],
  },
  {
    claim: "Carbs",
    matches: ["high in carbs", "^carbs"],
    exclusions: ["sugar", "lactose"],
  },
];

const DomArray = ["Protein", "whey"];
const Result = [];
const data = claimsArr
  .map((x) => [x.claim, x.matches])
  .flat(2);

for (let i = 0; i < DomArray.length; i++) {
  if (data.includes(DomArray[i])) {
    Result.push(DomArray[i]);
  } else {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Check Result for the outcome. I'm confident that less code is needed for this operation but it should do the job.

Comment: `.flat().flat()` could just be `.flat(2)`

Comment: Ah nice, thanks for the feedback, made the adjustment

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of  `filter` and `includes` functions of `Array` to achieve this.

```js
const claimsArr = [
  {
    claim: 'Protein',
    matches: ['high in protein', '^protein'],
    exclusions: ['whey', 'milk'],
  },
  {
    claim: 'Carbs',
    matches: ['high in carbs', '^carbs'],
    exclusions: ['sugar', 'lactose'],
  },
];
const DomArray = ['Protein', 'whey'];

const isAMatch = (str) => DomArray.some(dom => str.toLowerCase().includes(dom.toLowerCase()))

const result = claimsArr.reduce((a, c) => {
  const matches = [c.claim, ...c.matches].filter(isAMatch);
  a.push(...matches);
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: hi , this is close. i've edited my question for the expected output

Comment: Using flatMap and flat the desired output can be obtained.

Comment: put this after filter:

.flatMap( (item) => [item.claim, item.matches] ).flat()